# Which files can I ignore when I backup a Android studio project by myself?

Tags: android-studio

I create a Android Studio project which is located in the folder E:\Android_Studio_Project\MessageCleanup

I hope to backup the project by myself.

I think that all files located in the folder  E:\Android_Studio_Project\MessageCleanup\app\build\outputs\apk can be ignore, is it right?

And more, are there other files which can be ignored? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can ignore:

```
.gradle
.idea
app/build
build
local.properties
```

you could ignore

```
.gitignore (if you don't use git or dont want to exclude files from git)
```

The rest I would try to keep.

Comment: can I ignore all build folder inside different modules folders? like moduleOne/build/ and moduleTwo/build/ ?

Comment: @Michal yes, exactly.